# Values of override method not reflecting on main variables

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to change values of my class from an override method as shown below:

```
 public class QuestionAnalyser extends AppCompatActivity {
        String question;
        String entityIdentified;
        static boolean identified = false;
        DatabaseReference entityRef;
        TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface);

        }

        public void analyse(String userQues) {
            if (!(Interface.deviceLang.equals("en"))) {
                TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();
                question = t.translateText(userQues);
            } else {
                question = userQues;
            }
            question = question.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d", "");
            final String[] words = question.split(" ");
            getEntity(words);
            if (identified == true) {
                initialiseEntityServant(entityIdentified, question, words);
            } else {
                mimicOtherMessage("Sorry, I have failed to understand your question");

            }
            return;
        }

        private void getEntity(final String[] words) {
                    entityRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IRAdata").child("Entities");
                    entityRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot entity : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String[] synonyms = entity.child("syn").getValue().toString().split(",");
                                for (String syn : synonyms) {
                                    for (String word : words) {
                                        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(syn) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(syn)) {
                                            mimicOtherMessage("found");
                                            entityIdentified = entity.getKey();
                                            identified = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
            if (identified == false) {
                for (String yes : YesNo.yes) {
                    for (String w : words) {
                        if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(yes) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                            identified = true;
                            entityIdentified="basic";
                        }
                    }
                    for (String no : YesNo.no) {
                        for (String w : words) {
                            if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(no) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                                identified = true;
                                entityIdentified="basic";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

From the `analyse()` method i am calling the `getEntity()` method, the override method is working fine and is changing the value of `identified` and `entityIdentified` accordingly but, when the method is completed the updates are not reflected on the variables.

I have tried to debug, i could see the values changing in the override method, but when i check the values of the variables after the override method, i could only get the initial values. Somebody can help me on this please?

I have tried implementing threads as well, to make sure the method `getEntity()` gets completed before returning to the main, but the problem persists.

Comment: Need more clarification on your question. 
entityIdentified = entity.getKey(); //changed here but not after this method completes  
identified = true; //changed here but not after this method completes  
In override method OnDataChange() ?

Comment: when i am checking the values of the global variables after the override method OnDataChange(), the updates are not reflecting.

Comment: You are doing the changes with the assumption that your variables will be assigned instantly, from top to down, however, you should remember that the network operation with Firebase is running concurrently on a separate thread which might finish later. So you are seeing the variables being set, but they are set after the Firebase operation is done, which is independent of you code flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CoolGuyCG . I was suspecting something like this was happening but was not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written is not very detailed to me, but your logic could be restructured in a way, similar to what I have done below:

```
public class QuestionAnalyser extends AppCompatActivity {
        String question;
        String entityIdentified;
        static boolean identified = false;
        DatabaseReference entityRef;
        TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface);

        }

        public void analyse(String userQues) {
            if (!(Interface.deviceLang.equals("en"))) {
                TranslatorServant t = new TranslatorServant();
                question = t.translateText(userQues);
            } else {
                question = userQues;
            }
            question = question.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d", "");
            final String[] words = question.split(" ");
            getEntity(words);
            // remove any logic that depends on the return of getEntity(words) from here
            // it is best if the logic is called from within the Firebase call
        }

        private void getEntity(final String[] words) {
            entityRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IRAdata").child("Entities");
            entityRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot entity : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String[] synonyms = entity.child("syn").getValue().toString().split(",");
                        for (String syn : synonyms) {
                            for (String word : words) {
                                if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(syn) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(syn)) {
                                    mimicOtherMessage("found");
                                    entityIdentified = entity.getKey();
                                    identified = true;// under what condition will this be false
                                    // this is the best place to put the logic
                                    initialiseEntityServant(entityIdentified, question, words);
                                } else {
                                    identified = false;// I hope this condition for setting it to false is satisfactory
                                    mimicOtherMessage("Sorry, I have failed to understand your question");
                                    for (String yes : YesNo.yes) {
                                        for (String w : words) {
                                            if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(yes) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
                                                identified = true;
                                                entityIdentified = "basic";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        for (String no : YesNo.no) {
                                            for (String w : words) {
                                                if (w.equalsIgnoreCase(no) || question.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
                                                    identified = true;
                                                    entityIdentified = "basic";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            // the logic here will have to also be moved into the Firebase call
        }
    }
```

Note that, the parts that required the check on `identified` have all been moved to the `onDataChanged` method.

Comment: Yes, i get your point. But what if i need the on change method to be completed first before i proceed? Is there a way to put the firebase method execution in a thread and ensure the thread is executed first then resumes with the main?

Comment: That will cause your application to hang, it is a form of NetworkOnMainThread. You should never tie your application's main thread to a network operation, they should be asynchronous.
However, you can move almost all your operations into the `onDataChanged` method, where all your views can be updated with a `runOnUIThread` call.

Answer (score 0):

Please move your code written after getEntity()
Inside onDataChange() method. When onDataChange()  completes it will execute added code. You will get latest values in variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, like i mentioned above is there anyway using threads to make sure the onChange() method gets completed before the main thread resumes?